# How to uniformly sample vertices from a large graph with given distance from a fixed vertex?

Tags: sampling, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and some vertex $v_0\in V$, let $V_k=\{\,v\mid v\in V,d(v_0,v)=k\,\}$ be the set of all vertices with distance $k$ to $v_0$.

How can I quickly draw uniform samples from $V_k$ for a given $k$?  In my case, $G$ is implicitly defined as the state transition graph of some combinatorial puzzle and has about $10^{25}$ vertices with $|V_k|\approx 2.3676^k$, so enumerating the vertices in $V_k$ is not an option.  I am mostly interested in values of $k$ from $30$ to $50$ and would like to draw about $10^6$ samples for every $k$ in this range.

Comment: (1) Can you quickly evaluate $d(v_0,v)$ for a given $v$? (2) Can you quickly pick a random neighbor for a given $v$? (3) Does it matter if among the sample for a given $k$, there are some vertices that actually have $d(v_0,v)<k$? (You may see where I am heading.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa (1) the amount of time needed to evaluate this is proportional to $b^{d(v_0,v)}$.  Feasible for $k\le80$, instantly for $k\le40$.  (2) Yes.  Each vertex has between $2$ and $4$ neighbors, computing neighbors can be done instantly.  (3) No, if those vertices are also uniformly distributed and independent of each other and if I know the distribution of distances.  It would be better if such vertices would not be present.  For the $V_k$ I am interested in, membership can be decided quickly, so filtering out wrong vertices is feasible.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Though I do not see where you are going.  I tried random walks before, but I couldn't figure out how to make the resulting vertices uniformly distributed.

Comment: Ah, if you have regions with higher density, then a random walk may have a low(er) probability of traversing them... looks like you have a hard problem. Good luck!

Comment: @StephanKolassa The density is pretty uniform with the graph having six equally sized equivalence classes for its vertices (it's the state transition graph of the 24 puzzle, which is like the 15 puzzle but on a 5x5 grid).  The main difficulty lies in some vertices in $V_k$ having more than one path of length $k$ from $v_0$ to them and thus being picked with higher probability.  I wonder if it is possible to compensate for that.  The other difficulty is paths on which nodes overall have lower degree being picked less likely.

Comment: Without additional information about $G$ - I think the answer is no. You could easily imagine having a single vertex in $V_k$ accessible only by some small number of paths, while some other vertices are accessible by an exponentially large number of paths - so any kind of a walk will run into a serious problem. Thus, in order to be able to have some chance at finding a solution, you'll need to give more details on $G$. For example, is there some minimal distance between two neighbours? Even better would be if you could give a concrete description of $G$.

Comment: @MotiN The $G$ I'm interested in is the state transition graph of the 24-puzzle, which is a sliding tile puzzle like the 15 puzzle but on a 5x5 grid instead of a 4x4 grid.   Its diameter is unknown but it exhibits high regularity.  Though even then, if some nodes are twice as likely as others, that's already not really a uniform sample.

Comment: So as I understand - a vertex basically corresponds to a legal state, two vertices are neighbours if you can reach the other via a slide, and the distance between two vertices is the minimal number of slides needed to get from one to the other? There should be some symmetry here that can help solve this, I think.

Comment: @MotiN Indeed!  Though the only way symmetry seems immediately useful is for finding the number of paths from $v_0$ to a given $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [MotiN](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/99688)'s nice answer, I have decided to modify his procedure as follows:

Let $N(v)=\{\,w\mid w\in V, v\sim w\,\}$ be the neighborhood of $v$.  Let $d(v,w)$ be the length of the shortest path between $v$ and $w$.

We draw samples from $V_k$ by means of a random walk from $v_0$ with $k$ steps. At each step $i$, we pick a random edge from $v_{i+1}\in N(v_i)\setminus\{v_{i-1}\}$ with $v_1$ picked from $N(v_0)$, i.e. we do not pick the edge we just came from.  Further restrictions can be made (e.g. by means of FSM pruning) to improve the yield.

For each sample $v_k$, we determine all shortest paths to $v_0$ and thus $d(v_0, v_k)$.  If $d(v_0, v_k)=k$, we accept the sample, otherwise we reject it.  The probability of a sample being accepted is the yield $y=P\big(d(v_0, v_k)=k\big)$ which we compute during the sampling process.

For each accepted sample $v_k$, we have a set of shortest paths $S$ leading from $v_0$ to it.  We can use this set to compute the probability $P(v_k)$ of having chosen this sample by summing over all shortest paths to $v_k$:

$$P(v_k)=\sum_{v_0,\dots,v_k\in S}{1\over|N(v_0)|}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}{1\over|N(v_i)|-1}$$

Using the yield $y$, we can compute the chance $p$ of having chosen $v_k$ from all accepted samples:

$$p=P\big(v_k\mid d(v_0,v_k)=k\big)={P[v_k]\over y}$$

If $|V_k|$ is known, this can be used to compute a bias $b$ for the sample $v_k$

$$b=p\,|V_k|$$

This method allows us to sample vertices from $V_k$ and to compute the bias of each path leading to the sample picked.  While we do not get a uniform sample this way, we can compensate for the bias later on.

Comment: Can you add subscripts to the $C(\dot)$ functions to reflect the $i$ of $V_i$ they are for? it will make things clearer, thank you.

Comment: As well, I'd really suggest you do a calculation of the probability of selecting a vertex. This is really the only way to know if your algorithm is correct, rather than a gut feeling about it.

Comment: @MotiN it is $v_i\in V_i$ for all $i$.  I have used the same bias values as in your answer, except that I don't lose a factor of $3$ because I am not constrained to actual probabilities.

Comment: I don't think that $\sum_{v \in W} b(v)^{-1} = 1$ (of course you can reweight). And what happens with vertices not appearing in $W$? The result of your random walks will of course not include a lot of those; I think you really must do a proper calculation to include the probability of a node appearing in $W$ times the chance of it being chosen by the bootstrap sampling procedure. That first probability seems very difficult to me to calculate directly.

Comment: @MotiN Do you mean $S$ by *set of vertices chosen by the bootstrap sampling procedure?*

Comment: Well $S$ is defined by the above procedure. Weighting appropriately within $W$ to achieve $S$ seems very manageable. But weighting with respect to vertices in $V_k$ outside of $W$ (which are of course the majority) is the more difficult part. For example, there may be a node which has a very small number of paths to it, thus the chances of it being included in $W$ are lower than for other nodes. Is this corrected for by the weighting when it DOES make it into $W$?

Answer (score 2):

Given the information you've provided here is an approach I think works.

I will extend your notation to have $V_r(v)$ be the set of vertices of exactly distance $r$ from vertex, $v$. For convenience let $N(v)$ be the neighbours of $v$.

We note that for a given vertex, it has 2, 3 or 4 neighbours, which are easily determinable (constant time); i.e. $V_1(v)$ is trivial. We likewise assume that there is some constant cost for calculating $d(v_0, v)$ for all $v$ for which $d(v_0, v) \leq k$.

Assume that we have an efficient algorithm for all distances $\leq i$, we now show how to solve for $i+1$.

The algorithm is easy to explain - we choose some starting vertex $v_s$ uniformly at random from $V_i$. We then find its neighbours, and check their distance from $v_0$. 
Let $C(v_s) = V_{i+1} \bigcap N(v_s)$.
We note that, at least one vertex in $N(v_s)$ must be in $V_{i-1}$. Thus $|C(v_s)| \leq 3$. Then, with probability $\frac{3 - |C(v_s)|}{3}$ we reject $v_s$ and start again.

Otherwise, we choose a candidate $v_c$ from $C(v)$ uniformly at random: Let $n_c$ be the number of its neighbours which are in $V_i$. Then, we accept $v_c$ with probability $\frac{1}{n_c}$. Otherwise, reject $v_s$ and start again.

Correctness:
Define $I(v) = V_i \bigcap N(v)$.
Then, the probability of accepting a given $v \in V_{i+1}$ in a round is
$$
\sum_{v_s \in I(v)} P[v_s] P[v | v_s]
$$
where $P[v_s]$ is the probability of choosing $v_s$ in $V_i$ and is $1/|V_i|$, and $P[v | v_s]$ is the probability of accepting $v$ given that we chose $v_s$. 
$$
P[v |v_s] = \left(1 - \frac{3 - |C(v_s)|}{3}\right)\frac{1}{|C_v(s)|}\frac{1}{|I(v)|} = \frac{1}{3|I(v)|}
$$
Plugging this back in gives us a probability to accept $v$ of $\frac{1}{3V_i}$. Thus, the probability that an iteration accepts any member of $V_{i+1}$ is $\frac{V_{i+1}}{3V_i}$. Assuming the original poster's estimate that $V_i \approx 2.3676^i$, gives us that the probability an iteration succeeds is approximately $\frac{2.3676}{3}$.

Let the cost of determining neighbours be N, the cost of checking distance bound by $i+1$ be $D_{i+1}$, the cost of drawing from $V_i$ be $T_i$, then a round of the algorithm (which may or may not succeed) costs up to:
$T_i + N + 4*D_{i+1} + N + 4*D_{i+1}$. Unfortunately, this does mean that the cost of this algorithm to generate a single point is still exponential, albeit with a sizable improvement over enumeration, if one desires a small sample. If we assume that we can swallow the $D_i$ values into reasonable sized constants (in particular since the higher $i$ values where it is more costly they are calculated much less frequently than for lower $i$ values), we have an overall expected complexity of $O\left(\left(\frac{3}{2.3676}\right)^{k-1}\right)$.

Since for each $k$ we need to draw a point from a sub-sample, we get lower values of $k$ for free. For $k=30$, this works out to a complexity of about $10^3$, for $k=40$, this is roughly $10^4$, for $k=50$, this is $10^5$.

So determining whether this is feasible for you to sample $10^6$ points will depend on the horsepower you can bring to bear. For $k=50$ (which would give you all $k \leq 50$) it would be on the order of magnitude of $10^{11}$ work.

Comment: I'm sure you mean “note that, at least one vertex in $N(v_s)$ must be in $V_{i-1}$” instead

Comment: This algorithm makes sense.  I'm not entirely sure if the proof of correctness holds and I am a bit skeptical that the yield is high enough.  It seems like the yield of samples decreases by a constant factor with every iteration; seems like we have to start with quite a few samples to get enough in later iterations.

Comment: You are right regarding the complexity - I will update the answer to reflect the correct calculation

Comment: Note that this is basically a random walk starting from $v_0$ - we abandon the current path when either we can't move further away from $v_0$ from the current vertex, or probabilistically, to ensure that a uniform distribution for each distance.

Comment: The key point of your answer is that you found a way to account for bias gained throughout the random walk.  I propose the following modification to your algorithm: instead of discarding walks, always perform each walk to the end.  Then compute the probability you would have taken it with proper bias compensation.  Finally, do a weighted random sample on the resulting vertices where each vertex' weight is the reciprocal of the probability of taking it.  This should iron out the bias without throwing away too many samples.

Comment: I have added a revised variant of the algorithm as an answer.  Can you tell me if it makes sense?